# How to do url encoding for query parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, urlencode, query-string

I am new to Kotlin & I am trying to url encode my url which has query parameters.

```
private const val HREF = "date?July 8, 2019"
private const val ENCODED_HREF = print(URLEncoder.encode(HREF, "utf-8"))
private const val URL = "www.example.com/"+"$ENCODED_HREF"
```

Error: Const 'val' has type 'Unit'. Only primitives and Strings are allowed for `private const val ENCODED_HREF`

Comment: Could you please remove or rename your question?? This is NOTHING to do with a URL encoding, but it is a general Kotlin misunderstanding that you put up as a question about URLs... Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

`const` expressions in Kotlin must be known at compile time. Also, as @Stanislav points out, print is a `Unit` (i.e., `void` in Java) method, so printing something destroys its value.

Since your constants are computed, the use of `val` (which is a runtime constant) is appropriate. The following compiles.

```
private const val HREF = "date?July 8, 2019"
private val ENCODED_HREF = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(HREF, "utf-8")
private val URL = "www.example.com/"+"$ENCODED_HREF"
```

Comment: private val URL = "www.example.com/$ENCODED_HREF"

Comment: yes, the string-interpolated, non-concatenated version is superior, I was looking to make minimal changes to the submission to answer the narrow question asked.

Answer (score 13):

Seems like the returning type of the `print` method is *Unit*, so that's why `ENCODED_HREF` has this type. Just take the URLEncoder part out of the method to fix it:

```
private const val ENCODED_HREF = URLEncoder.encode(HREF, "utf-8")
```

Comment: Why do people post "answers" that are not simply wrong if they could instead just copy&paste it to see it immediately? :-/